# Can't connect chronograf to influxdb2

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, influxdb, chronograf

I installed [influxdata/influxdb2](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/influxdata/influxdb2) and [influxdata/chronograf](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/influxdata/chronograf) with default-values.

I can successfully log in to InfluxDB-UI after port-forwarding to localhost and reading the admin-password from the kubernetes-secret. However, if I try to set up Chronograf and connect to InfluxDB using the following settings:

[image]

I see a notification saying:

```
Unable to connect to InfluxDB Influx 1: Error contacting source
```

when using v1 authentication (username, password) and I see:

```
Unable to connect to InfluxDB Influx 1: Failed to fetch
```

when using v2 auth (org, token).

**Reproduction:**

```bash
kind create cluster
helm install influxdb2 influxdata/influxdb2  # prints '...influxdb accessible through its service-name: influxdb2' among other things
helm install chronograf influxdata/chronograf
kubectl port-forward chronograf 8888:8888
# Set up in browser
```

Did I do something in the wrong order? I'm pretty new to the TICK-stack - please be gentle

Comment: Refer to the similar [Github issue](https://github.com/influxdata/docs.influxdata.com-ARCHIVE/issues/2870), which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It's not applicable though. The issues aren't comparable because the context is so different. The issue doesn't have a solution. All the recommended fixes don't work in my case.